# How to lock the screen to be only portrait view only

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hey guys i am trying to stick my website screen to be portrait only but it not working properly using this css query it affect the height of my website. is there any other solutions to lock the website to be only portrait?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  html {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use the media query to notify the user to rotate the device and explain that the site is intended for portrait mode only

Comment: We have to use script to achieve this goal. Because css doesn't properly render this goal using rotate(-90deg)

Comment: @DeclanPossnett Actually i don't want to approach this i want to lock the portrait mode so when the user rotate his device the screen keep the same nothing happen.

Comment: If you want portrait would you not have to change `orientation: landscape` to `orientation: portrait`

Comment: @WojtekT no because this is a media query that applies when the device is in landscape orientation, it's correct

Comment: @DeclanPossnett yeah i tried to change also now and it flipped everything

Comment: @HeshamElMasry take a look at [CSS Sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/) a library that will give you more browser support with transforms.